# Elasticsearch - count with dynamic value

Tags: sql, json, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm trying to do a count(1) with a dynamic value.
Example:

```
SELECT A, 
       B, 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) 
          FROM TABLE_X 
         WHERE TABLE_X.SOMEVALUE = TABLE_A.ID)
FROM TABLE_A INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.ID
WHERE TABLE_A.SOMEINFO = :something
```

How can I do a filter/query in Elasticsearch that found the TABLE_A.ID at the outer select and use it in the inner select (the one with count())?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The point of elasticsearch is to denormalize your data, so you shouldn't be making any joins.

Instead, (imo) you should be indexing your data with the data already joined.  Ultimately though, you have a few options

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to be sure that there is other way than rewrite the mapping.